# Emacs randomly weird hangs or suspend

Tags: suspend

Here is the output from Emacs `strace`:

I run command `sudo htop`, when Emacs suspend and `[C-g]` does not work. I enable `strace` in `htop` on Emacs PID.

Here is the log [gist](https://gist.github.com/stardiviner/eb53130667a800526e4548015eadc0ac) output which occurs repeatly:

```
Trace of process 20592 - emacs

--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\1z\220\0\0\0\0\6\0\200\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_cont
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base=";\0\5\0S. \3\0\0\0\0\r\0\5\0\16\0\26\0008\0\4\0S. \3\4\0\0\0"..., iov_len=1132}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 1132
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\0\255\220\0\0\0\0\235\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_c
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base="\22\2\f\0\34\0\240\3\235\3\0\0\37\0\0\0\10\0\26\0\30\0\0\0006\0\5\0\r\0\21\0"..., iov_len=92}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}]
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\241\10\257\220\27\0 \3,\2\0\0007\0\1\0\r\0\21\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base=";\0\5\0P. \3\0\0\0\0J\0J\2X\2\26\0008\0\4\0P. \3\4\0\0\0"..., iov_len=1880}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) = 1880
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\241\10\4\221\27\0 \3,\2\0\0009\0\4\0\r\0\21\0\10\0\0\0\5\0\4\0\3\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base="\31\0\v\0\34\0\240\3\0\0\0\0!\10\0\0\34\0\240\3,\2\0\0;\0\1\0\r\0\21\0"..., iov_len=44}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) =
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base="\221\3\4\0\1\0\0\0\224\0 \3\3|\270\0\31\0\v\0\34\0\240\3\0\0\0\0!\10\0\0"..., iov_len=60}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 1
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\241\10\7\221\27\0 \3,\2\0\0009\0\4\0\r\0\21\0\10\0\0\0\5\0\4\0\3\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(5, [{iov_base="\31\0\v\0\34\0\240\3\0\0\0\0!\10\0\0\34\0\240\3,\2\0\0;\0\1\0\r\0\21\0"..., iov_len=44}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 3) =
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(6, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
read(6, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
--- SIGIO {si_signo=SIGIO, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 91
recvmsg(5, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="U\2\10\221X^\353\2\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\37\205\3\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_co
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
recvmsg(5, {msg_namelen=0}, 0)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}], 4, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
brk(0xf703000)                          = 0xf703000
```

*UPDATE*:

I use Emacs profiler to found out the reason now.

Comment: Try sending SIGUSR2 to get a backtrace.

Comment: @YoungFrog Can't get any useful information from this strace?

Comment: I can't (but it does not mean nobody can).